# Wordpress redirect url when user access homepage and is not following anyone

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

So, I'm developing a Behance-like network with following option. As default, when a user logs in he is redirected to the homepage to see a timeline with the content of the people he follows, but people that just registered will see no posts in that timeline (since he didn't get to follow people yet).

So, I need to redirect logged users that access the homepage and are following 0 users to url example.com/#tabber_frontpage_new_posts, so that he sees the overall latest posts, not only the posts from the people the follows.

In this theme I'm counting and printing the 'following' number like this - you may find some of these parameters useful:

```
<?php echo count( _core::method( '_follow' , 'get_following' , $author_id ) ); ?>
```

Could someone figure out a function to do what I need?
Thank you!

Comment: What does that echo? The number of people the user is following?

Comment: `if(count( _core::method( '_follow' , 'get_following' , $author_id ) ) == 0){header('Location: yoururlhere');exit;}`

Comment: @TomHart well, it does redirect, but it will redirect any user (even those following others), from any url within the site (should be only when accessing homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
if ( is_home() && count( _core::method( '_follow' , 'get_following' , $author_id ) ) == 0 ) {
    wp_redirect( '/page/to/redirect/to' );
    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: for some reason, it is also redirecting any user (my admin account is following 1 other user, and it's being redirected).